# wget command to browse directory named X with different parent name

Tags: command-line, wget, directory, windows-console

I'm using the following command:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -nd -r -l5 --no-parent -A "*revisions.txt" https://mysite.com/folder/test/product1/
```

to get all files containing "revisions.txt" but my structure is like this:

```
> https://mysite.com/folder/test/product1/xxx/final/
> https://mysite.com/folder/test/product1/yy/rc/
> https://mysite.com/folder/test/product1/yy/beta/
> https://mysite.com/folder/test/product2/zzz/final/
> https://mysite.com/folder/test/product2/yy/rc/
> https://mysite.com/folder/test/product2/xx/beta/
> https://mysite.com/folder/test/product2/xxx/alpha/
> https://mysite.com/folder/test/product2/zz/alpha/
```

...
And I only want to browse directories "rc" and "final". The problem is that I have more 50 products and this number is increasing with time so this has to be "dynamic".

How can I browse only rc and final to get all revisions.txt from these two directories? The parent directories can have different names.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
wget -P ./revisions/ --no-check-certificate -nd -r -l8 -A "*revisions.txt" --exclude-directories="*/BETA/*","*/ALPHA/*" --no-parent https://mysite.com/folder/test/
```